# Special characters in webparts

Tags: 2010

Currently I have a problem with some German characters like ö,ä,ü and so on in my web part. SharePoint didn’t show these characters correctly. It just shows some crazy stuff like Ã¶.

The Element.xml use `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`. 
The Sharepoint header uses `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`.

If I add a special character in the text field in SharePoint, the characters will show correctly. 
How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using the Unicode character set isn't enough, you'll need to change every special character with the corresponding html-code
Here's a list:
[Special characters list](http://webdesign.about.com/library/bl_htmlcodes.htm)

If you are reading the xml in c#, you could use the following to convert

```
string TestString = "This is a <Test String>.";
string EncodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(TestString);
//Output: This is a &lt;Test String&gt;.
```

Comment: Why i must change every special character? If i develop in php that is not necessary, if i use unicode. At the moment, the character is in asp ListItem, that is very time-consuming if i have to change every special character by myself.

Comment: Do you use Visual studio? Otherwise you can search and replace all characters with one click. But you'll need to that for every special character. Another way to change it inside the asp listitems is maybe with this (didn't test it):http://www.wap.w3schools.com/asp/met_htmlencode.asp

Comment: Yes i uses VS. Okay, then i will change every character. I thought their would be a better solution. Thanks guys.